# Docker, docker-compose, networking: how to configure?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I want to organise docker network to match this scheme:

[image]

I have already created docker-compose file and can run multiple container groups by changing COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME. Now I want to connect to the host machine from containers in each group. 
How should I configure service on the host machine and how can I connect to him from containers? I don't want to expose host machine port to Internet, it should be available only from containers.

Comment: @johnharris85 I've tried to bind service host to 172.17.0.1:3306 (I get ip from docker0 interface) and then connect to this address from container, but I see "Connection refused" error, but ping is works.

Comment: Works fine for me (binding on docker0 bridge then hitting from containers). Can you post exactly how you're configuring mysql and what commands you're using in the containers etc... Also post your compose file.

Comment: @johnharris85 Oh, I've just tried it on clean docker & mysql installation and it works. It seems that MySQL tried to bind to address when docker0 interface was not initialised yet.

Comment: Is there a way to launch mysql only when interface is ready? I'm using systemctl to run it.

Comment: Why don't you run mysql in a container?

Comment: Out of curiosity could you post your compose file somewhere? I'm trying to achieve the same thing right now.